# Review the edits, Approval Not Allowed

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits

I saw a little red flag near the top of my StackOverFlow browser window.

I clicked.

The message said that someone had edited my message to make it more clear.

There were, I think, (this was yesterday) two options; (1) review and (2) approve.

Since I'm so smart and know everything in the world better than everybody else alive anywhere on planet earth (oh yeah) I thought that I needed to stop this malicious tampering at once.

Turns out the guy was a stranger and an angel; corrected four little clueless newbee glitches I did, and made the thing ten times easier to comprehend.

So, I thought I would "Approve" his edits.

BARRRRRRRNNNNNNK !!!!! Penalty.  You can't approve edits with less than 2000 points

At that moment, I think I had 80 points total.

It was an interesting experience to be offered the option of approving the edits to my own post, and then when I approved them, to be immediately told that I'm not allowed to approve them.

Comment: Strange, because you can approve or reject edits on your own posts. Perhaps it had already been approved or rejected by the time you got to it?

Comment: Pretty sure you did approve the edit and, after approving, the queue will then move to the next item, and that item you *don't* have the ability to review.  You don't have any recent activity, so clearly this didn't just happen.  I believe the workflow was fixed rather quickly if it happened a while ago.  If you post a link to the related question we can confirm if you actually approved it or not.

Comment: I thought the post owner was always allowed to approve edits. Are you sure you were logged in on the site where you had pending edits?

Comment: [This edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1295026) was approved before you got to it.

Comment: I think it happened yesterday; I didn't document it perfectly, but it was in the past few days, I'm confident

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Normally* you get to approve or reject suggested edits on your own posts, regardless of what reputation you have.

In this case, the [suggested edit in question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1295026) was approved within mere minutes, so you didn't get to vote on it at all.

If you clicked the `Approve` button instead after the 3rd 'Approve' vote was already cast, you would have been taken to the next suggested item in the queue, which you don't have the rights to see, giving you the error message that confused you so.